# iOS push notifications only showing badges. need sounds and banners too

Tags: ios, cordova, apns-php

I am currently sending push notifications to 2 different apps using the same methods, but one of them only shows only **Badges**. If I visit **Notifications** from **Settings** it displays only "**Badges**" instead of **"Badges, Sounds, Banners"**.

I am using the https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push plugin.

I tried reseting so it would ask for first time push request, tried another device, and repeatedly called the plugins `init` function which calls

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)]
```

but with the same result.

If I am on the lock screen it shows up. If I check notification center its there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am setting notification like this:

```
UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
```

It works fine.
Hope this help.