# Meteor raix:push: Only "Badges" instead of "Badges, Sounds, Banners" in Notifications settings

Tags: meteor, push-notification

In the Notifications section in the Settings app, my app only has "Badges" listed under it where it should have "Badges, Sounds, Banners".

Due to this I don't get "notified" when a new notification comes in, i.e. no banner, no sound, no vibrations. The notification shows up in the notifications tray and on the lock screen and the badge number updates, but there are no alerts.

Any ideas how to fix this?

My config.push.json looks like this:

`{ "apn": {
 "passphrase": "passphrase", 
"key": "PushChatKey.pem", 
"cert": "PushChatCert.pem" }, 
"production":false,
 "badge": true, 
"sound": true, 
"alert": true, 
"vibrate": true }`

And I send notifications like this:

```
`Push.send({ from: 'Test', title: 'Hello',text: 'World', badge: 4, query: {}, sound: 'default' });`
```

(Similar to [iOS push notifications only showing badges. need sounds and banners too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32151446/ios-push-notifications-only-showing-badges-need-sounds-and-banners-too) but using different framework.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this using the Push.Configure({}) setup on both server and client.

Server code:

```
Push.Configure({
    apn:{
        passphrase:'password',
        certData: Assets.getText('enter certificate pem file name'),
        keyData: Assets.getText('enter key pem file name')
    },
    production: false //or true if production
});
```

**Client code** (including the alert:true is what did the trick for me):

```
Push.Configure({
    badge:true,
    sound:true,
    alert:true
});
```

Comment: Saved me hours of work! Hopefully this doesn't break when RAIX is updated.